# Excel macro if file exist

Tags: vba, excel

So like the topic title says, i am looking for some help with a macro.
I need it for my job so every time a clients backup is executed he sends a mail to a mailbox and these mails are exported in the folder.
This is the mail format:

> Backup Rapport Success Clients name File Backup Set Taak 2012-10-23 (20 30)

The macro's needs to do a few things :

- Extract the name of the client
- extract or the backup whas SUccess or failed or missed
- And write the success or failed message in the right cell

Is this even possible?

```
Public Function FileFolderExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
'Author       : Ken Puls (www.excelguru.ca)
'Macro Purpose: Check if a file or folder exists
    On Error GoTo EarlyExit
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True

EarlyExit:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Sub TestFolderExistence()
'Author       : Ken Puls (www.excelguru.ca)
'Macro Purpose: Test if directory exists
    If FileFolderExists("c:\test") Then
        MsgBox "Folder exists!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Folder does not exist!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, it's probably possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: atm i extract the mails from my outlook into a direcotry and then i have this bit off code to check if the file exist,                   Public Function FileFolderExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
'Author       : Ken Puls (www.excelguru.ca)
'Macro Purpose: Check if a file or folder exists
    On Error GoTo EarlyExit
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
    
EarlyExit:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Comment: the problem is i dont have a clue on how to write the macro thats search for the name of the client the date en if the backup whas success or not...

Comment: @kjellsneessens: Please don't post a bunch of code in a comment. It's obviously unreadable. Just edit your question and place it there.

Comment: Sorry for that its my first time i post here

Comment: OK, what you can do is figure out the logic to interpret the string. Is the success-status always the third word? Can client name contain spaces? If not is it always the fourth word? If it does conatin spaces, how can you find the client name? This you can do without knowing how to program that logic. Then you can ask more specific questions, and you will have shown some effort. Most often you do not get complete solutions here on SO. :)

Comment: oke Olle this is a example mail i get Backup Rapport  Geslaagd    ClientName   File Backup Set   Taak 2012-10-23 (20 30), the 3th word is always the success status and the 4th always the ClientName and the 9th always the date in the same format, btw Geslaagd means Success in Dutch

Comment: Here are some hints on commands for string handling you can look up: `Split`, `InStr`, `Mid`, `Left` and `Right`.

Comment: If ClientName always in one word you could use `Split("MailString", " ")`. It will give you an array of the words, and you can use the third and fourth to find status and client name. If name does contain spaces, it wouldn't work, because you don't know how many of the words are part of the client name.

Comment: but i dont get how that i can input the data into the right cell meaning the exact date and client name, i checked and the clients name never contains any spaces

Comment: Hi, I think you can finish this task in one step, instead of saving file and then later on process the file.

I am interested in the part "Right cell" 
Can I Assume you have a excel sheet with Column A -- DATE
Column B -- USER NAME 
Column C -- Result (Success/Fail) ?

Answer (score 0):

The following will split the string into words (but it will only work if ClientName is one word).

```
Sub Test()
    Const sIn As String = "Backup Rapport Geslaagd ClientName File Backup Set Taak 2012-10-23 (20 30), "
    Dim sArr() As String

    sArr = Split(sIn, Space(1))

    Debug.Print "Success=" & sArr(2)
    Debug.Print "ClientName=" & sArr(3)
    Debug.Print "Date=" & sArr(8)
End Sub
```

There are a lot of ways to enter text into cells. One example:

```
Range("A1").Value = "Hello"

Range("A2").Value = sArr(2)
```

**EDIT**

Expanded the sub to take a string and a range and enter text:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitMailStringAndEnterValues(psMail As String, poRange As Range)
    Dim sArr() As String

    '***** Check that poRange is an object
    If Not poRange Is Nothing Then
        sArr = Split(psMail, Space(1))

        '***** Check that sArr is an array
        '***** and that it contains at least 9 strings
        If IsArray(sArr) And UBound(sArr) >= 8 Then
            '***** Enter values starting in range poRange and use
            '***** offset to place other values to the right
            poRange.Value = sArr(2)                 'Success
            poRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = sArr(3)    'ClientName
            poRange.Offset(0, 2).Value = sArr(8)    'Date
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Now call this for each mail-string, instead of writing the whole string in a column:

```
Call SplitMailStringAndEnterValues("Backup Rapport Geslaagd ClientName File Backup Set Taak 2012-10-23 (20 30)", Range("Sheet2!A2"))
```

Comment: thank you olle but in you example i need to put every day and for each client the Subject off the email by hand in the code i think?

Comment: Use the `Dir` command to look for files in a folder. Lopp through them, and call the code once for each, instead of using `sIn`. One more hint: you can turn the sub `Test` into functions to return the desired values from the mail string.

Comment: OK, then. Put the cursor somewhere in the `Dir` command and press F1 to get help on how `Dir` works (it's in your `FileFolderExists` example). Hope you have help installed...

Comment: Or use [an online version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff846392.aspx).

Comment: ok thx again Olle i am one step away from completing i think, so atm my data from my c:\test\ folder comes in my xls file, but how can i let the macro scan the cells for the names defind in you script?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment - what do you mean by "scan the cells for the names defined in your script"?

Comment: so now all my data of the folder is entered in excel in diferent cell so each mail = 1 cell

Comment: Ok, see the edit to the answer. Added a sub that takes a string and a range where to put it. In my example I used cell "A2" in "Sheet2", but you could use any range, but if the range is bigger than _one_ cell, it will look pretty strange.

Comment: is it possible to let it chose the cell automatticly on name an date?

Comment: Sure. Look up the `Find` command. It can be called on any `Range` object, and returns a new `Range` object representing the cell where the search term was found or `Nothing` if the search term was not found.

Comment: @kjellsneessens Did you get it to work? If my answer was of any help to you, select the answer by clicking the checkmark beside it.